# How to get the type of a varible

Tags: python, list, function, types

I created a function that took a list as a parameter and removed either a space or a number. Code below:

```
def cleaner(List, filter_out=' '):
    if filter_out == ' ':
        for i in List:
            if i == ' ':
                List.remove(' ')
    if filter_out == 'int':
        for i in List:
            if type(i) == int:
                List.remove(i)
```

I tested it using a list like so:

```
myList = ['h' ' ', 'g', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'p']
print(cleaner(myList, filter_out='int'))
```

I expected to get `['h' ' ', 'g', 'p']`
but instead printed out `['h ', 'g', 2, 4, 'p']`
Why did it leave the `1` and `2`? I thought that it would filter out all numbers in the list.

Comment: first thing's first you don't use builtin type names as variables or parameters

Comment: second thing's second you don't remove from list while iterating it

Comment: that print should print none

Comment: @Marko We'll I know, but i thought that sense i wrote `type(i)` i should compare it to a builtin type `int`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing items from a list while iterating it results in bad consequences:

```
>>> nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> for x in nums:
...     print x
...     nums.remove(x)
... 
1
3
```

You start at index 0.  You print `nums[0]`, `1`.  You then remove it.  The next index is `1`.  Well, `[nums[1]` is `3` because now the list is `[2, 3, 4]`.  You print that, and remove it.  The list is now `[2, 4]`, and you are at the third index.  Since `nums[2]` does not exist, the loop ends, skipping two numbers.  What you should do is take advantage of the builtin functions:

```
myList = ...
myList = filter(lambda x: not isinstance(x, int), myList)
```

For the example of `' '`, it would be:

```
myList = ...
myList = filter(str.strip, myList)
```

or

```
myList = filter(lambda x: x != ' ', myList)
```

**Note**: The Python 3 `filter()` function returns a `filter` object, not a list.  That makes it more efficient if you are just iterating, but if you truly need a list, you can use `list(filter(...))`.

All of these make a copy of the list instead of doing their work in place.  If you want it in place, use `myList[:] = ...` instead of `myList = ...` (in the `filter()` line).  Note that a Python 3 `filter` object does not need to be converted to a list for this to work.

Comment: In Python 3, the filter function will return a generator object instead of a list. This avoids constructing a complete list of the results and does not make any difference if all you do with the result is iterate over it.

If you need an actual list object in Python 3, use `myList = list(filter(lambda x: x != ' ', myList))`

Answer (score 1):

This would be a proper way to do it for medium sized lists

```
 def cleaner(lst,filter_item = ' '):
        if filter_item == ' ':
            for i in list(lst):
                if i == ' ':
                    lst.remove(' ')
        elif filter_item == 'int':
            for i in list(lst):
                if type(i) == int:
                    lst.remove(i)

 myList = ['h' ' ', 'g', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'p']
 cleaner(myList, 'int')
 print(myList)
```

or a nicer way:

```
 def cleaner(lst,filter_item = ' '):
     retval = None
     if filter_item == ' ':
         retval = [i for i in lst if i != ' ']
     elif filter_item == 'int':
         retval = [i for i in lst if type(i) != int]
     return retval 

myList = ['h' ' ', 'g', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'p']
a=cleaner(myList)
print(a)
#['h ', 'g', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'p']
a=cleaner(myList,'int')
print(a)
#['h ', 'g', 'p']
```

Comment: isn't `filter` a reserved built-in function in python?

Comment: @Marco hmm.. Surprising. Your code still seems to work fine  :)

Comment: @Mr.Python dangerously, you're allowed to overwrite builtin functions in python. so it works fine because the default `filter` has been overwritten by the function's parameter definitions

Comment: Yeah :) that's just what I wanted to say to him

Comment: @xgord Oh believe me i know very well that using a builtin function or keyword as variable is a dangerous idea. I was just surprised that Marko's code didn't fail horribly.

Comment: no, sadly python does not prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot

Comment: why are you supprised ? :) your code makes no sense, let's say you're walking to the mountain that's 100 meters tall ( that's only data you know) and that mountain every turn get's 1 meter smaller, while you climb you will eventually see it's 30 meters tall and be supprised. Where do you walk further ?

Comment: @Marko No. I just mean't that i'm surprised that python didn't spit out a **error** for your code.